# When using pyqt on Windows, what does the QProcess.pid() result represent?

Tags: python, pyqt, qprocess

The documentation for [`QProcess.pid()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprocess.html#pid) says:

> Returns the native process identifier for the running process, if available. If no process is currently running, 0 is returned.

What does this mean?

This code is used to explain my confusion. I am using Python 2.7.9, PyQt 4 and Windows 7:

```
import  sys, os, time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class testLaunch(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        self.process.start('calc')
        self.process.waitForStarted(1000)
        print "PID:", int(self.process.pid())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = testLaunch()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This launches the Windows calculator application, as expected. In the task manager, it shows the following:

[image: Calculator PID]

This shows my PID as 8304. The `print` statement from my application though, shows:

```
PID: 44353984
```

What does this represent and how does it compare to the 8304 PID the task manager reports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Unix systems, the pid will be a `qint64`, but on Windows it will be `struct` like this:

```cpp
typedef struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION {
  HANDLE hProcess;
  HANDLE hThread;
  DWORD  dwProcessId;
  DWORD  dwThreadId;
} PROCESS_INFORMATION, *LPPROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

PyQt will return a `sip.voidptr` for such a struct, which is why you are seeing that weird value when you convert it with `int()`. The actual pid you want is the `dwProcessId`, so you will need to use something like ctypes to extract it.

Here is some completely untested code which might do the job:

```python
import ctypes

class WinProcInfo(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('hProcess', ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE),
        ('hThread', ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE),
        ('dwProcessID', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('dwThreadID', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ]
LPWinProcInfo = ctypes.POINTER(WinProcInfo)

lp = ctypes.cast(int(self.process.pid()), LPWinProcInfo)
print(lp.contents.dwProcessID)
```