# qtimer crashes when created in constructor or static

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, crash

So, i have finally found this odd issue that i have found no answer for.

I'm creating a small gui, launching an application in a separate window and then polling the state of this app using a qtimer.

```
    process_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(process_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkFlashProcess()));
    process_timer->start(100);
```

So this works. But i would rather not create a new timer every time, so i placed the creation of process_timer in the constructor of the gui:

```
Flasher::Flasher(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Flasher)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    process_timer = new QTimer(this);
}
```

Now this leads to a crash and the output:
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::timeout() to Flasher::checkFlashProcess()

Same for this:

```
Flasher::Flasher(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::Flasher),
process_timer(new QTimer)
{...
```

QTimer *process_timer is defined in the application header.

I have also tried defining process_timer as non dynamic:

```
    header.h:
        QTimer process_timer;
    code.cpp
    void Flasher::on_flashButton_clicked()
    {
    (...)
    hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, process_pid );
    if(hProcess)
    {
        qDebug() << "Got handle for process!";
        connect(&process_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkFlashProcess()));
        process_timer.start(30);
    }
```

This also leads to a crash.

Callback:

```
 void Flasher::checkFlashProcess()
 {
        qDebug() << "Got handle for process!";
 }
```

But Why is this? I guess that the timer does not get created in the constructor, but creating objects in the constructor should not be a problem right? And why would the static version crash also, would this be the same issue?

Comment: Where is the `connect` call, and when is it called relative to the construction of the `Flasher` object instance ?

Comment: Connect is called in a slot for a button on the gui.
`void Flasher::on_flashButton_clicked()
{
...
    hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, process_pid );
    if(hProcess)
    {
        qDebug() << "Got handle for process!";
        process_timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(process_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkFlashProcess()));
        process_timer->start(30);
    }`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `process_timer` is not set to null somewhere in between creation and call to `connect()`? Did you stop at the `connect()` call in debugger and investigated it?

Comment: What you have just updated in your question regarding "static way" will not even compile. You cannot have non-pointer variable named `process_timer` and then define it with `process_timer = new QTimer(this);`. You mixed up some of your trials here.

Comment: Yes, it's only used to monitor another application for a short while. This occured during me testing how to use the timer so i only had the creation and the start of the timer in the code. I have not tried the debugger(also i don't have that set up)

Oh yeah sorry, copied from my current code and missed that.

Comment: a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would probably be beneficial in this case to make sure the problem is isolated as much as possible.

Comment: Aside from obviously some error in the code, any reason you are polling instead of using `QProcess` and connecting to its signals`

Comment: @KevinKrammer Yes, i have tried that in all manners i could find/think of. But I'm calling a command line application(in windows) and it prints status updated a few times each second. Using start from qprocess i have not been able to get it to show the output in a terminal and trying to stream stdout to a textbox in the gui is just to awful, there seems to be no way to avoid the buffering leading to the output only updating every 4-5 seconds, which is just awful.If i could use a proper qprocess i could actually get the returnvalue of the application aswell, this is just a compromise.

Comment: @PetterOlofsson so when you are using QProcess it doesn't fire its readyReadStandardOutput() signal?

Comment: @KevinKrammer It does, it's just not syncronised to the actual output of the program. The signal comes every five seconds and then i can read about one page of the continuous output, there seems to be no way around this. It actually works pretty good with programs that do not write that much to stdout but for example eclipse does this aswell. (You might think this sounds like a heck of alot of output, it's just using \r to update a progressbar)

Comment: Strange, I wonder why this gets buffered so much. Maybe there is a low level API one could call to prevent that.

Comment: I agree, it blows my mind that the readyReadStandardOutput signal is not emitted every time there is output. Either someone thought out something 'clever' there or the interface between the program and the receiver is less than great. From my tests there almost seems to be a timeout between reading some output and waiting for more, then eventually dumping it when the stream keeps coming in. I tried some calls to change the buffering to to no effect, from all the posts i have read there seems like no one has found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that this was not related to qtimer but rather a memory problem. I was looking around alot for how to get the process handle in windows and mostly found sources about unix. Then between [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509089/when-using-pyqt-on-windows-what-does-the-qprocess-pid-result-represent) [two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I apperently got things mixed up and ended up using a DWORD for the process_pid, which seems to have been placed just before the timer in memory. Thus calling openprocess caused corruption and led to the crash. Creating the timer after starting the application "fixed" this by restoring the timer again.

Another lesson learned, and using a qint64 for pid from qProcess to OpenProcess works fine. Hopefully someone else can find this when looking to do something similar and can avoid the hassle, thanks for kicking me to create a mcve to isolate the issue.

Comment: How did you find out the cause of the memory leak ? What is mcve ?